Alter Login Auth in Elsa Studio
I'm trying to change the default authentication of Elsa Studio WASM, but I'm not finding a way to implement authentication using JWT, to replace the application's default login which is: login:password
Password: admin
Could anyone help me with an example of this implementation?
I would like to keep using the login layout, but overwriting the current authentication model, with my own
Elsa WASM documentation: https://v3.elsaworkflows.io/docs/installation/elsa-studio-blazorserver

This article helped me solve my problem, changing Elsa's authentication to integrate it with my app
https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/discussions/4814
But it is also possible to disable authentication itself behind the command.
add into your elsa appsettings:
{
   "Shell": {
       "DisableAuthorization": true
    }
}

And add into your program:
builder.Services.AddShell(options => configuration.GetSection("Shell").Bind(options));

And implement your own authentication, using conventional methods, just remembering that elsa will always need to receive a user claim, to authenticate the routes.
